# Getting an error when trying to get data from a csv then displaying it in a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Does anyone know why im getting this error, im trying to pull the if statements into the category array then display it in a graph with times array.

This is error that i get when i run it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "pandas/index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3843)
 File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 303, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6501)
 TypeError: an integer is required

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/jacob/Projects/CIS2302/CW2/ddd_cw2/temporal_analysis  /test.py", line 33, in <module>
   plot = seaborn.stripplot(data=data, x='day', y='category')
    File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 2501, in stripplot
jitter, split, orient, color, palette)
File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 1108, in __init__
self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
 File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 199, in establish_variables
group_names)
File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py", line 241, in _group_longform
grouped_vals = vals.groupby(grouper)
File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3436, in groupby
sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze)
File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1311, in groupby
return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 418, in __init__
 level=level, sort=sort)
 File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2264, in _get_grouper
in_axis, name, gpr = True, gpr, obj[gpr]
File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 557, in __getitem__
result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
 File "/home/jacob/.virtualenvs/cis2303/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1790, in get_value
return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
 File "pandas/index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3204)
 File "pandas/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2903)
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3908)
KeyError: 'item'
```

This is my code that i am using to try and make this work.

code:

```
import seaborn
from matplotlib import pyplot
from csv import DictReader
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime

data = {'category': [],
    'day': [],
    'time': []}

with open('/home/jacob/Projects/CIS2302/CW2/ddd_cw2/cleaned_logs/u_ex150601.log.csv') as in_f:
reader = DictReader(in_f)
for line in reader:
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(line['time_received_isoformat'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    data['day'].append(timestamp.day)
    data['time'].append(timestamp.hour * 60 + timestamp.minute)
    if 'search' in line['request_url_path']:
        data['category'].append('search')
    elif 'browse' in line['request_url_path']:
        data['category'].append('browse')
    elif 'add-to-cart' in line['request_url_path'] or 'remove-from-cart' in line['request_url_path']:
        data['category'].append('cart')
    elif 'book' in line['request_url_path']:
        data['category'].append('item')
    elif line['request_url_path'] == '/baseline/':
        data['category'].append('baseline')
    elif line['request_url_path'] == '/explore/' or line['request_url_path'] == '/review/':
        data['category'].append('modern')
    else:
        print(line['request_url_path'])

plot = seaborn.stripplot(data=data, x='day', y='category')
plot.get_figure().savefig('/home/jacob/Projects/CIS2302/CW2/ddd_cw2    /temporal_graphs/' + 'category_day_stripplot' + '.png')
pyplot.close()
```

Comment: That does not look like the full trace back?

Comment: no its not, ill update it now